# User Roles Not Sticking

Tags: customization, user-roles

I have added a custom user role of super_poster, basically they make 20 posts and once they hit $postlimit get auto-moved back down to contributer level, the moving down and post counting works ok, my problem is that the wp system adds the user into "none" instead of into contributer role

```
if ($count_posts >= $postlimit) {
    $current_user->remove_role( 'super_poster' );
    $current_user->add_role( 'contributer' );

  }
```

contributer is set for new user default on sign-up, so the situation i have is in wp-admin user edit page i can see the newly moved (into contributer from super poster) has still got "additional capabilities of contributer" however user role dropdown says --No role for this site --

wp-admin users page shows the super_poster as in user group "none"

what gives?

Comment: please try to give your best on phrasing your Q. It's extremly hard to understand what you're trying to ask. So far i understood that you wait until an author has 20 posts and then remove the contributer role from him and add the role of super_poster. I don't get around what happens then. Further more i don't understand your intention. I also don't know which capabilites you assigned to the super poster role and else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use `WP_User::set_role( 'contributor' )` instead. It unsets all current roles and sets the new one (the argument) too.

So the above would be

```
if ($count_posts >= $postlimit) {
  $current_user->set_role( 'contributor' );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

"contributor" is spelled with an O, perhaps you've just misspelled it?

Comment: LOL, I'll bet that's what the problem was!

Comment: Well i'l be jiggered! a typo...lol

Comment: Spelling always count!!

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my late reply, work and family life took control, regarding the issue i had, i tried John P Bloch suggestion and it resolved to being exactly the same: user role = None and No Role For This Site, i did quite a lot of researching via codex and couldnt realy come up with much, it dawned on me that im using a theme that sets user role as contributer on sign-up by default, so i tried the little block below and it does exactly what i need which is when user role is changed from custom role to Contributer, shows them in wp user panel as being a contributer rather than having no role.

```
//$current_user->set_role( 'contributer' );
$current_user->set_role(get_option('default_role'));
```

Dont know if its truly semantic from a WP way of doing this but it seems to be working the way i want it to do.

Regards Martin